# Pointer errors with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
 DIR * d;
 int dsize=0;
 struct dirent * de;
 char *dir[1024];
 d=opendir(".");
 while ((de = readdir(d)))
            {                                                                               
              if((de->d_type) & DT_DIR)
                {
                  dir[dsize]= de->d_name;
                  dsize++;
                }
             }
```

I'm trying to store the address of the file names into a array of char pointers.

A bit rusty on pointers I went back and read some pages of pointer review but I'm 
not sure what I'm doing wrong.. Keeps telling me "warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast". Is my syntax just off because of the struct?

Comment: what are `dirent`, `DT_DIR` and `d_name`

Comment: OT: [`readdir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) can, and will, overwrite each filename in the DIR structure as you move from file to file. You don't "own" that memory, the implementation does. If you want to keep the names, you have to make copies of them (i.e.. break out `malloc()` or a fixed-buffer solution). From "man 3 readdir" : *"The data returned by readdir() may be overwritten by subsequent calls to readdir() for the same directory stream.*"

Comment: @ ivaylo its part of a ia include <dirent.h> DT_DIR tells if its a directory or not, d_name is the name of the dir(char array) and dirent is just a structure from the libary

Comment: It compiles on gcc after removing the lonely "char" on the third line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot store the pointers that way. They are overwritten every time, you call `readdir` and then you have a dangling pointer to invalid memory. If you want to store the dir entries, you must copy the whole name, not just the pointer

```
char dir[1024][256];
while (de = readdir(d)) {
    if (de->d_type & DT_DIR) {
        if (dsize < 1024) {
            strcpy(dir[dsize], de->d_name);
            dsize++;
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget the check for the `dir` array bounds. Otherwise you risk overwriting the stack, which might result in a crash.

Comment: +1 simple solution. both bounds should be checked, the string length and the `dir` array length, but that horse is halfway through the glue factory already =P. nice answer.

Comment: Ah that make sense after reading WhozCraig link I think I see it. Nice simple answer